# Conforma array en C# con llave string

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero conforma un **array** en **C#** donde la **llave** se a un **string** y después separar la **llave** del **value** con un **foreach** en **php** conformo el **array** de la siguiente manera Ej.:

```
$array['key_name'] = "value1";
```

He buscado un poco en Internet y encontré lo siguiente:

```
    var datos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    datos ["fondo"] = "LA9018-58-896.png";
    datos ["codigo"] = "LA9018";
```

y para extraer el valor solo seria así:

```
string aValue = datos["fondo"];
```

> Lo que obtengo

**LA9018-58-896.png**

El problema que tengo es que solo me traer una sola **llave**  y lo que quiero es hacerlo de forma dinámica con un ***foreach***. Guardando en una variable la **llave** y en otra el **value**.

Comment: Estas confundiendo los conceptos. En C# un array es un conjunto de objetos que pueden ser indexados únicamente por un número entero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C# los arrays siempre tienen índices numéricos.

Lo que estás creando es un objeto ´Dictionary` en el que cada elemento es un par clave-valor, en tu caso ambos de tipo string.

Puedes recorrer los elementos del objeto Dictionary con un foreach como haces en php. Cada elemento obtenido en la iteración será un par clave-valor, de forma que podrás acceder a la clave a través de la propiedad Key y al valor a través de la propiedad Value:

```
        var datos = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["fondo"] = "LA9018-58-896.png",
            ["codigo"] = "LA9018"
        };

        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
            // Tratamiento del elemento item
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, fue la solución a mi problema